# FireDAC FDBatchMoveTextReader change filed data type at runtime

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am trying to parse different text files using `FDBatchMoveTextReader`. I use `GuessFormat` procedure solely to determine field count. Therefore, I set `AnalyzeSample` to 10 lines. I am trying to manually set each field's data type to string after `GuessFormat` runs. When I run execute I get error saying

> [FireDAC][Comp][DM]-607. Bad text value [17,5] format for mapping item [->B]. '17,5' is not a valid integer value.

Above `B` is my column name in the SQL Server Express which is also a `nvarchar(60)`.

How can I actually set data type to string?

My code is as follows.

```
FDBatchMoveTextReader1.FileName := Edit1.Text;
FDBatchMove1.GuessFormat([taDelimSep, taFields]);

case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
  0: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecANSI;
  1: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecDefault;
  2: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecUTF16;
  3: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecUTF8;
end;

for i := 0 to FDBatchMoveTextReader1.DataDef.Fields.Count-1 do begin
  // Set all field data type as string
  FDBatchMoveTextReader1.DataDef.Fields[i].DataType := atString;
end;

FDBatchMove1.Execute;
```

Comment: Clear FDBatchMove1.Analyze

Comment: I appreciate a code sample for clearing "Analyze", please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solved the problem:

```
FDBatchMoveTextReader1.FileName := Edit1.Text;
FDBatchMove1.GuessFormat([taDelimSep, taFields]);

case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
  0: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecANSI;
  1: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecDefault;
  2: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecUTF16;
  3: FDBatchMoveTextReader1.Encoding := ecUTF8;
end;

for i := 0 to FDBatchMoveTextReader1.DataDef.Fields.Count-1 do begin
  // Set all field data type as string
  FDBatchMoveTextReader1.DataDef.Fields[i].DataType := atString;
end;

FDBatchMove1.Analyze := [];

FDBatchMove1.Execute;
```

Thanks for putting me in rigth direction da-soft.